# Why spectrogram from librosa library have different time duration of the actual audio track?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, spectrogram

I'm trying to plot the wave plot and spectrogram from a 16000Hz 16-bit .wav speech audio. I have successfully obtained the below plots:

[image: wave plot and spectrogram of the word 'about']

However, the time value on the spectrogram is not correct. I'm certain that my sampling rate is consistent (16000Hz) throughout the program, but I still cannot get the correct time value for the spectrogram.

Below is my python script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np

y, sr = librosa.load('about_TTS_0792.wav', sr=16000)
print("Current audio sampling rate: ", sr)

print("Audio Duration:", librosa.get_duration(y=y, sr=sr))

D = librosa.stft(y, hop_length=64, win_length=256)  # STFT of y
S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(D), ref=np.max)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr, ax=ax[0])
img = librosa.display.specshow(S_db, sr=sr, x_axis='s', y_axis='linear',ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set(title='Linear spectrogram')
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax[1], format="%+2.f dB")
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Output for this code:

```
Current audio sampling rate:  16000

Audio Duration: 0.792
```

I don't know what I have missed that can cause the inconsistent time values on the x-axis. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time axis for an STFT spectrogram depends on two factors: the sample rate and the hop length.

When you compute the STFT, you specify `hop_length=64, win_length=256`. Note that this information is not contained in `D` or `S_db`—*librosa* leans more towards a functional approach, not an object-oriented approach.

So when you then go on to show the spectrogram using [librosa.display.specshow](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html), you have to specify the `hop_length`, which you missed. Therefore the default `hop_length=512` is used, which leads to a factor `512 / 64 = 8` error. I.e. `0.792 * 8 = 6.336`, which matches what you see in your spectrograms.

Also, I believe `x_axis='s'` should rather be `x_axis='time'`.

So changing

```
img = librosa.display.specshow(S_db, sr=sr, x_axis='s', y_axis='linear',ax=ax[1])
```

to

```
img = librosa.display.specshow(S_db, sr=sr, hop_length=64, x_axis='time', y_axis='linear', ax=ax[1])
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: Clear explanation. Adding hop_length fixed the error. Thank you Hendrik.